# Stop/Resume activities and onCreate in Android

Tags: android, oncreate

I'm a new Android developer and I have a question. After users login, I need to get some data from an external `URL` and display them on one of my activities. But I've been reading and found this:

> When your activity comes back to the foreground from the stopped state, it receives a call to onRestart(). The system also calls the
>   onStart() method, which happens every time your activity becomes
>   visible (whether being restarted or created for the first time).

And this

> Caution: Your activity will be destroyed and recreated each time the
>   user rotates the screen. When the screen changes orientation, the
>   system destroys and recreates the foreground activity because the
>   screen configuration has changed and your activity might need to load
>   alternative resources (such as the layout).

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

So, it looks like I should not get the data I need on the `onCreate` method. Then where? In a previous activity and saving the data in the phone memory? That doesn't sound good to me.

Thanks in advance.

---

edit

I'm using `AsyncTask` as suggested, but everytime I switch the phone orientation, `onCreate` method is called.

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AsyncResponse {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ReadJSONTask jsonTask = new ReadJSONTask();
        jsonTask.delegate = this;
        jsonTask.execute("http://www.myweb.com/myscript.php");
    }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(String output) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

ReadJSONTask class:

```
public class ReadJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;
    public String res;
    public Boolean finish = false;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        String response = null;
        String adres = url[0];

        URL url_HTTPRequest = null;
        try {
            url_HTTPRequest = new URL(adres);
            response = transfer(url_HTTPRequest);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("URL ERROR", "MalformedURLException");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("URL ERROR", "exc");
        }

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("mylog", "result= " + result);
        delegate.processFinish(result);
    }

    public String transfer(URL url) throws IOException {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        // inputStream = url.openStream();
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
        String line = bin.readLine();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\r\n");
            line = bin.readLine();
        }
        inputStream.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

And the interface is just:

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(String output);
}
```

As I said, everytime I switch the phone orientation all the async process is performed (and the `Toast` shows up). That's exactly what I wanted to avoid in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

you dont need Stop/Resume activities you can use **AsyncTask** class and **doInBackGround** method when get data from external url and show to user process Dialog for waiting

Answer (score 2):

Never ever try to get the data from `URL` on `Main thread`. Always use `AsyncTask` for getting the data from `URL`

Comment: Thank you guys. I'll do some research about AsyncTask.

Comment: I just edited, AsyncTask doesn't answer my original question. Please check it out.

Comment: No need to implement the AsyncResponse follow this example http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Great tutorial. Thanks. I followed the tutorial but still happens the same problem with the orientation of the phone. Every time I switch the orientation all data are loaded again.

Answer (score 1):

You can write in the same activity, but not in the main thread. Maybe **AsyncTask** will help.